# positive semidefiniteness of the Hessian of $f\circ g$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $g\in C^2(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $D^2g(x)$ be positive semidefinite for all $x\in\Omega$. Let furthermore $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ with $f',f''\geq 0$. Show that $D^2(f\circ g)(x)$ is positive semidefinite, for all $x\in\Omega$.

---

I've tried to compute this explicitly using matrices and got stuck:
$y^TD^2(f\circ g)(x)\cdot y=y^TD(D(f\circ g)(x))(y)=y^T(D(Df(g(x))\circ Dg(x))(y))$. How do I continue from here (or is there an easier method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify this using the chain rule. First, for $x \in \Omega$, we have $D(f \circ g)(x) = Df(g(x)) Dg(x)$. Differentiating again, making use of the product rule, we have $D^2(f \circ g)(x) =D^2f(g(x)) Dg(x)^\top Dg(x) + Df(g(x)) D^2g(x)$.

Let $x \in \Omega, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then:
\begin{align*}
v^\top D^2(f\circ g)(x)v &= v^\top[D^2f(g(x)) Dg(x)^\top Dg(x) + Df(g(x)) D^2g(x))]v \\
&= v^\top [D^2f(g(x)) Dg(x)^\top Dg(x)] v + v^\top [Df(g(x)) D^2g(x))]v
\end{align*}

Consider the first term.
$$v^\top [D^2f(g(x)) Dg(x)^\top Dg(x)] v = D^2f(g(x)) v^\top Dg(x)^\top Dg(x) v = D^2 f(g(x)) (Dg(x)v)^2 \geq 0$$
since $D^2 f(g(x)) \geq 0$ as $f'' \geq 0$.

Consider the second term.
$$v^\top [Df(g(x)) D^2g(x))]v = Df(g(x)) (v^\top D^2g(x)v) \geq 0$$
since $Df(g(x)) \geq 0 $ as $f' \geq 0$ and $D^2g(x)$ is positive semidefinite.

Putting the two inequalities together, we conclude $D^2(f\circ g)(x)$ is positive semidefinite.